# carouFredSel: Create a function for next / prev buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using [carouFredSel](http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/) to create multiple carousels on the same page. If you look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nx8vq/) you will see that there are two carousels, but only one is able to be scrolled with the next / prev buttons.

Without adding a class or ID, I am trying to tell the buttons to only scroll the corresponding carousel. I believe this be accomplished with a function, but I'm not entirely sure how. Something like this:

```
prev: {
    button: function() {
        $(this).next('.prev');
        }
},
```

Comment: I should mention, the reason I do not want to use a class or ID to solve this problem is because I am generating these columns with WordPress. Since all the columns will have the same properties, I would prefer not to repeat code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give this a look, it's right in the documentation:

```
prev: {
    button: function() {
        return $(this).parent().siblings(".prev");
        }
    },
next: {
    button: function() {
        return $(this).parent().siblings(".next");
        }
    }
```

[Working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nx8vq/1/)

oh and notice, I took out the `key`, because then you would have to have the carousels synchronized... and you can have one or the other, not both. (unless you conditionally assigned keys, but there goes your small code)

--
http://caroufredsel.frebsite.nl/code-examples/configuration.php
search: "Get the HTML-elements for the buttons and the container dynamically"

Comment: Ah! I was close. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wicked close... yeah, I had to read that doc for something else once and I remembered seeing it in there... glad I could help mate!

Comment: I ended up implementing the keybaord control in a different way. So in my case it's not a problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think thats better set an ID.

```
$("#list1").carouFredSel({
    direction: "up",
    auto : false,
    items: 3,
    prev : "#prev1",
    next : "#next1"
});   

$("#list2").carouFredSel({
    direction: "up",
    auto : false,
    items: 3,
    prev : "#prev2",
    next : "#next2"
});
```

[See a working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/5Gk9s/12/)

Answer (score 0):

may be this one is usefull for you.in my page its workin good.

```
prev: {
       button  : ".prev"
},
next: {
       button  : ".next"
},
```